# Facebooker and Rails3 with OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebooker, facebook-opengraph

The facebook rest API is apparently deprecated and is going to disapear soon.

This Api is replaced by the new OpenGraph Api. Right ?

I'm looking for a way to replace Facebooker with a plugin able to handle the facebook open graph and working with Rails3.

I looked over the web and i didn't found something interesting about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since you posted your question, but maybe this answer will still help...

I am using [fbgraph](http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph) to interact with the OpenGraph API. AFAIK the gem is compatible with Rails3.

Answer (score 0):

Arkan, you should look into the following. They all work with Rails 3.

- fbgraph
- fb_graph
- oauth2
- devise
- devise_oauth2_canvas_facebook

Comment: When i asked, it was in june and the situation was not the same ... Thanks anyway